# Turn HDMI display off while keeping audio on

Tags: audio, hdmi, kodi

I am currently wrestling with a configuration headache involving my RPi4, Kodi and an audio receiver (and a TV that doesn't support CEC standby)…

Even after installing an HDMI splitter to separate hdmi going to TV and SPDIF going to receiver,  I cannot seem to find a way to only turn off the display signal (only way to get the TV to eventually go to sleep) without also turning off audio (which I want to keep playing, when using Kodi for music).

Both `tvservice` and `vcgencmd` simply shut down the power to the HDMI out, which obviously shuts down the audio.

Unfortunately I cannot set `hdmi_blanking = 0`, as it would then start going to sleep in the middle of videos playing in Kodi…

Mirroring HDMI output so that shutting down one (the TV) doesn't affect the other (receiver) [also seems impossible when running Kodi on a Pi](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=355728)…

Is there any command or workaround I can use, to stop sending a video signal while keeping audio on?

Comment: Pretty sure this is an absurdly irritating oversight in the HDMI protocol itself -- you cannot "disable" the video side.   External smart TV boxes with no separate audio out have the same problem -- when running an audio app you can't turn the screen off while listening if you need the HDMI for sound.

Comment: google `linux hdmi sound bar`

Comment: I stand corrected.  Someone please tell Amazon.

Comment: @goldilocks well, in the case of a TV, it stands to reason that putting the device to standby will cut off the sound anyway. Merely turning the screen black is fairly easy (and has limited impact)… My use case is a bit different, since I'm trying to keep feeding audio through the HDMI splitter to the AV through TOSLink…

Comment: @jsotola was your comment directed at the other commenter? if it was meant for me, I'm afraid I can't find anything particularly useful to my specific case…

Comment: Totally off-topic Dave but I wish turning the screen black were "fairly easy" -- you can get it pretty dark by adjusting a bunch of things (just one in my case does not get you that close to "black") then whoops, want to skip the next song?  You need the visual interface back...just gotta raise that and that and that again.  What is fairly easy by comparison is throwing a blanket over the thing (which is what I end up doing).  *I should have used a pi!*

Comment: @Dave my comment was aimed at you ... i briefly searched on the web and it seems that in linux it may he possible to enable only sound over HDMI ... that is why i posted the comment

Comment: @jsotola OK, then I did use your search terms, and while there were a few people with somewhat similar problems, none were applicable to the current situation (Raspberry + XMBC)… Can you share a relevant link?

Comment: @goldilocks turning the screen "dark" (but not off) merely requires fiddling with what's being displayed, and is generally something that depends on what full-screen app you might be using. It's definitely supported by XMBC, for example…

Comment: Not so Spotifiy.  Both they and Amazon (Fire TV sticks) have known about the issue for years -- a lot of complaints and feature requests.  So it is definitely a corner case, it just seems like a fix would be so easy why not? Even the TV makers could do this, but needing to access audio output through a TV without video, also a corner.  Boo... @jsotola : That's the impression I got looking at that stuff as well, although I did not dive in very deeply.  Based on that Dave you might want to try this at  [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), just downplay the "raspberry pi" aspect.